# How does the classloader find resources?

Tags: java, dependency-injection

I am reviewing a small github example project ([shagie/TestingWithHsqldb](https://github.com/shagie/TestingWithHsqldb)) and have stumbled across a convention that is new to me and was hoping someone could help me understand what I am looking at.

---

The project is organized under the main src directory as such...

```
src/main/resources/connection_config.properties
src/main/java/com/shagie/dbtest/db/DBConnection.java
src/main/java/com/shagie/dbtest/db/DataAccess.java

src/test/resources/connection_config.properties
src/test/java/com/shagie/dbtest/db/DataAccessTest.java
```

The code in `DBConnection.java` is called both from `DataAccess.java` under the 'main' directory as well as the `DataAccessTest.java` in the 'test' directory.

In the file `DBConnection.java` there is the following statement that imports the `connection_config.properties` file:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream in = GetClass().getResourceAsStream("/connection_config.properties");
prop.load(in);
in.close();
```

---

My Questions...

- How is the properties file being found in the "resources" directory if the call is structured as `getResourceAsStream("/connection_config.properties")`? Doesn't that path mean it should look at the root directory (main or test) for the properties file?
- Since `DBConnection.java` doesn't change it's root 'main' directory, how is it that the properties file comes from the 'test' directory when executing `DataAccessTest.java`
- <strike>I assume this pattern is related to dependency injection and unit testing. Is there a name for this specific pattern? Where is a good place to learn more about it?</strike>

**EDIT:** Adjusting question to focus on the `ClassLoader`'s `getResource` functionality instead of dependency injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with dependency injection but with how `ClassLoader`s resolve resource paths.

1) This might be a bit confusing coming from a Linux background indeed `getResourceAsStream(resource)` has different rules. As per the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-):

> If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of
>   the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.

So the leading slash here only tells the class loader how to get the absolute name (whether the name you passed should be prepended with the package name or not), not that it should be looking "at the root" (in the test/main folders). What is the root and how resolution works depends on the class loader you are using. By default (in this case) resources are searched in the `resources` folder. You can write your own `ClassLoader` and change that behavior.

2) Again, when calling `getResources()` or `getResourceAsStream()` the class delegates it to the `ClassLoader` which loaded this class. If you are running unit tests (Junit or something similar) then the `ClassLoader` will know that it's supposed to look for resources in `test` folder not `main`.

Comment: There is no indication in the source code that it is using anything but the default class loader (If that is not the case, how do I know if I am using something other than the default class loader?). If `/connection_config.properties` is an absolute name, then I don't understand how the class loader knows to look in `resources` directory.

I've looked at the [Location-Independent Access to Resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html) guide on the docs site, and its not any clearer to me why the `resources` directory would be used to find the file.

Comment: @HariSeldon ah there's a bit of a misunderstanding here, it doesn't have to be in the `resources` directory, that's just a project layout convention used in Java nowadays. Put it anywhere else and it should still work.

Comment: OK... that makes it more clear... I am going to work out some example code for myself as well. Thanks for taking the time :)

Comment: @HariSeldon there's more stuff you probably are wondering about like the prop file in `test`, for instance try removing it from `src/test/resources/`, then the classloader will load the one from "production" code. If you're very brave you can debug in what order the classloader is looking through the paths :-)